# laravel 5.2 building api Auth

Tags: php, laravel, api, cordova, authentication

Im building an a hybrid app in cordova and using laravel as api, but im a little bit confused with the Auth:api, I could not find any tuto explaining what I want!
I want to know how can a user get authenticated from the app on  his phone to my laravel api, as far as I know I am gonna use a api_token (random string), that I am gonna store on Users table, that is fine but how am I gonna authenticate the user with it and how to keep the user sending it with all requests? can I just store it in the app and keep sending it? Im stuck with the login! how to login the user for the first time? Im I gonna use the login provided by laravel or build a new one for this??
help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the use of `auth:api` guard in Laravel 5.2 see https://andrew.cool/blog/64/How-to-use-API-tokens-for-authentication-in-Laravel-5-2 it seems quite thorough.

Now for the rest of your questions:

**For the login you will need an API call that the client will use to login**, let's say:

`POST logins`

with body:

```
{
  "email": "user@example.com",
  "password": "password"
}
```

which in Laravel could represented as:

`Route:post('logins', 'MyApiController@login');`

Now in the `MyApiController::login()` method you will check the credentials provided `email`, `password` and if they match with a record in your database then you will respond with an `api_token`. That api_token can be created on the fly (make it hard to break) or if the user has already an `api_token` you can return that one. It depends in your expiration policy, if you want a login to also mean a logout for other devices etc.

If the credentials do not match then you will respond with a `400 Bad Request` and the client in that case should attempt to login again.

For your other question, **yes the client app MUST remember the `api_token`  and include it in every API call that needs it**.

Take care that Laravel searches for the `api_token` in a specific order as seen from the code below (that is Laravel 5.4). In the link I gave you above there are instructions on how to include the `api_token`.

```
public function getTokenForRequest()
{
    $token = $this->request->query($this->inputKey);

    if (empty($token)) {
        $token = $this->request->input($this->inputKey);
    }

    if (empty($token)) {
        $token = $this->request->bearerToken();
    }

    if (empty($token)) {
        $token = $this->request->getPassword();
    }

    return $token;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, If I did this  can this `Auth::guard('api')->user()` return the Authenticated user ?

Comment: Yes it will, see TokenGuard::user() to see the details

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/support/remote-auth use this package its a easy to intigrate and provide lots of feature to manage users in remotaly